# Binary search tree program gives me "expected an identifier" error

Tags: c

```
void delete()
{
    int data;
 
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        printf("No elements in a tree to delete");
        return;
    }
    printf("Enter the data to be deleted : ");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    t1 = root;
    t2 = root;
    search1(root, data);
}
```

the delete function gives a missing identifier error. and I am not sure which identifier to declare there.

If anyone needs full code, it's here: https://katb.in/enoyizedoja

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: It only gives "Expected an identifier"

Comment: "delete" is a c++ keyword. You can't use it as a function name.

Comment: ahhh that fixed it. thanks loocid

Comment: Do you accidentally run your program through a C++ compiler? Then you are no longer using C but C++.